# Magento admin panel is not loading after installing extensions

Tags: magento

I had a web site installed with few extension. I moved the theme of my web site to a new installation on another server. Now I am trying to install all those extension again, I am getting errors. Sometimes Magento admin panel does not load completely and sometimes the configuration link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Install extensions one-by-one. Clear cache after each install and test if everything works properly or not. Then install another extension and follow the steps. If something goes wrong, it's because of your last extension that you installed.

Also to note here, some extensions may require other extension to work. There is a `depends` tag in each module registration xml file. Install in proper order, and everything should work.

Comment: Shut off compilation before even starting the process. Empty its code store and only recompile and enable after the last module is in place and the site has been running without issue for a day or two. Also, don't bother enabling compilation if it was not enabled in the first place. One or more of your freshly installed modules will be incompatible with the compilation Kludge and it's bye-bye site till you find out how to manually disable the compiler.

Comment: i did like this but when i installed the module QAZ_Qbanner,it got installed successfully.but i get  blank dashboard of magneto.

Comment: I disabled the compilation and now its working fine.But when i enabled it again,i get the same error should i keep it disabled

Comment: @user2084269 leave it disabled. do you also have APC or other PHP op-code module enabled?